# Kuzzle anonymous user to access to a plugin?

Tags: plugins, kuzzle

Hi i tried to give anonymous user to access to a plugin but it still does not work what you think i am doing wrong?
kuzzle-core-plugin-boilerplate/NewController:Object
actions:Object
getamount:true
should anonymous get any other privilege to access the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the anonymous user is not restricted and can call every API method (core methods and also [plugin methods](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/plugins/guides/controller)).

For example, if you have a plugin named `iot` in the [manifest](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/plugins/guides/manual-setup/prerequisites/#manifest-json) and you declare the following controller:

```
this.controllers = {
  sensors: {
    register: request => /* ... */
  }
}
```

Then you can call this custom API action with the following WebSocket payload:

```
{
  "controller": "iot/sensors",
  "action": "register",
  "body": /* request body */
}
```

If you want to call this API method with the Http protocol then you have to [declare a route](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/plugins/guides/controllers/#example):

```
this.routes = [
  { verb: 'POST', url: '/sensors', controller: 'sensors', action: 'register' }
]
```

Then you can call it with Curl for example: `curl -X POST http://localhost:7512/_plugin/iot/sensors`